# Call a method from another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been doing this application for a while and now I want to call a method from by main form and include it into another form to make it run what I want. In my main form this is the method that I have:

```
Public Sub MostrarResultadoTotal()
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "......"
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Query = "SELECT 
                CAST(SUM(CAST(Filesize as float)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
                FROM infofile"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        If SqlDR.Read() Then
            If SqlDR.IsDBNull(0) Then
                lblResultadoTotal.Text = "0,00"
            Else
                lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)
            End If
        End If
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And I want to call this on a delete button. Do you have any idea how can I solve my problem?

This is the method:

```
'Mudar a cor das labels dependendos to tamanho total
    Sub ChangeLabelColor()
        If lblResultadoTotal.Text <= 3.9 Then
            lblResultadoTotal.ForeColor = Color.Green
            lblGB.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf (lblResultadoTotal.Text >= 4) And (lblResultadoTotal.Text <= 6.9) Then
            lblResultadoTotal.ForeColor = Color.Orange
            lblGB.ForeColor = Color.Orange
        ElseIf lblResultadoTotal.Text >= 7 Then
            lblResultadoTotal.ForeColor = Color.Red
            lblGB.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
```

Comment: making something `Shared` is always the worst possible solution - you'd be avised to pass instances around - and use them. Thats called "OOP".

Comment: Unrelated: You may be interested to know about [`Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) - it's shorthand for the try/finally you have, and can aid readability.

Comment: `Shared is always the worst possible solution` I would hate to say it's not. How do you pass a method/function around? Please explain... Also if he has a class instance he doesn't need the shared... On another note, make it a function in a separate class and call it where ever you need to...

Comment: I've tried to do that but it gave me an error after I change it 'Cannot refer to an instance of a class from within a shared method or shared member....'

Comment: Yes. And Sql too @Zaggler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, your method contains data access logic, which should be separated from your UI layer logic (Forms). It should be in a separate class, which is then called by both forms.

```
Friend Class DataAccess
    Public Function MostrarResultadoTotal() As String
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "......"
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            Query = "SELECT 
                    CAST(SUM(CAST(Filesize as float)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
                    FROM infofile"
            SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            If SqlDR.Read() Then
                If SqlDR.IsDBNull(0) Then
                    Return "0,00"
                Else
                    Return SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Always close connection 
            SQLCon.Close()
            SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, from you forms, just declare an instance of your date access logic:

```
Dim dataAccess = New DataAccess();
```

And call it:

```
lblResultadoTotal.Text = dataAccess.MostrarResultadoTotal()
```

**For your label colors**

Changing label color is UI logic, and from your example, it is also reusable. So you should consider creating a new class to manage common UI logic:

```
Friend Class CommonUILogic

    Function GetLabelColor(value As Integer) As Color
        If value <= 3.9 Then
            Return Color.Green
        ElseIf (value >= 4) And (value <= 6.9) Then
            Return Color.Orange
        ElseIf value >= 7 Then
            Return Color.Red
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Then you can call it that way:

```
Dim uiLogic = New CommonUILogic()

Dim labelColor = uiLogic.GetLabelColor(Integer.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text))

lblResultadoTotal.ForeColor = labelColor
lblGB.ForeColor = labelColor
```

Comment: So, in this case I have labels. I should copy/paste all the method that I have for a class?

Comment: @Miggs create a seperate class, paste your method in it and make it `Shared`. Then you can call it :)

Comment: Suggesting layer separation is an advanced topic. Consider adding a concrete code example and/or links to relevant articles.

Comment: I would make it a function not a method as you are returning one field... This way you can display it anywhere you want.

Comment: But know it gave me erros on the label. @Zaggler

Comment: Everything that is related to sql and labels give me error because it does not make part of this class

Comment: No don't put the label code in there. You need to call the method... For example `lblResultadoTotal.Text = YOURNEWCLASS.FUNCTION` remove the label code inside the function. Also just `import` the namespaces in the new class and you should be good to go!

Comment: I updated the example to remove UI code from the function. You will also need to add the missing Imports to you new class.

Comment: @PhilDulac If its a function you may need to `End Function` not `End Sub`... :)

Comment: Ok this is working for now. I have to make it for the others. But thank you for your helpfully help :D

Comment: Another think I have a method where I clean the labels so in that case what should I do? @Zaggler

Comment: I've updated with the method that I am trying to call @Zaggler

Comment: It's always related to the scope of what you're doing. Cleaning the labels' text is UI logic, it shouldn't be in you data access class. Then, it depends if you reuse the same code. If so, there are multiple ways of doing it: you can create a new class to host common UI logic, you could have a base class, etc.  If it's not reusable, make private subs in your forms.

Comment: So, I should create a new class just for the UI things? @PhilDulac

Comment: Based on what I see from your example, yes. Make your Sub a Function that returns the color and gets the Number in parameter: `Friend Function GetLabelColor(value As integer) As Color`

Comment: I can't just put (int value) because it gives me an erro

Comment: When calling the function: `label.ForeColor = instance.GetLabelColor(Integer.Parse(label.Text))`

Comment: I think I got it. So what I do with the labels that I have in the labels?

Comment: But in the friend function I just make the `Friend Function ChangeLabelColor(value As Integer) As Color` and then `Return value`? @PhilDulac

Comment: It will return me always the same color because im not calling the `value` on the form right? @PhilDulac

Comment: @Miggs It will return the same value as your original example because you pass the label's text in parameter to the function: `uiLogic.GetLabelColor(Integer.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text))`